SwiftData Unit Testing EXC_BREAKPOINT on insert
Hello,
I'm trying to unit test a SwiftData Model, but I'm facing a weird situation and couldn't find an answer to the problem.
The first solution I'll show you does not work, the second one does.
First of all, here's my @Model :
@Model
class Movie {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

First solution (doesn't work) :
var modelContainer: ModelContainer {
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: Movie.self, configurations: ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true))
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to create container.")
    }
}

@MainActor
final class Tests: XCTestCase {
    private var context: ModelContext!

    override func setUp() {
        context = modelContainer.mainContext
    }

    func testCountShouldBeOne() {
        let movie = Movie(name: "NewMovie")
        context.insert(movie) // Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT

        do {
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Movie>()
            let movies = try context.fetch(descriptor)

            XCTAssertEqual(movies.count, 1)
        } catch {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
}

Second solution (works) :
(modelContainer remains the same)

@MainActor
final class Tests: XCTestCase {
    private var container: ModelContainer!

    override func setUp() {
        container = modelContainer
    }

    func testCountShouldBeOne() {
        let movie = Movie(name: "NewMovie")
        container.mainContext.insert(movie)

        do {
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Movie>()
            let movies = try container.mainContext.fetch(descriptor)

            XCTAssertEqual(movies.count, 1)
        } catch {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
}

So the difference is I now have to call container.mainContext for SwiftData operations, and it works but in the first solution, where I had : context.something, I got the EXC_BREAKPOINT.
Does somebody know why?
Thank you !

In both cases, modelContainer is a computed property that always returns a new ModelContainer when you access it.
In the first case, you just get the modelContext out of the ModelContainer, without holding onto the ModelContainer. The ModelContainer gets deallocated as a result and you are now left with a ModelContext that doesn't have an associated container.
In the second case, you do store the ModelContainer as a stored property of the Tests class, so the test case is keeping it alive.
The exact syntax you use to access the model context isn't really relevant. The key point here is whether or not you are keeping the ModelContainer returned by the computed property alive. If you feel container.mainContext is too long, you can write a computed property like this in the Tests class.
var modelContext: ModelContext { container.mainContext }


I see, thanks a lot ! Last thing, my code is inspired from this tutorial on youtube : https://youtu.be/OF7TLbMu1ZQ?si=Xk_JelKRYZF154Cb&t=1115, if you want to search manually, it's : "Writing Unit Tests for SwiftData Domain Logic". If you watch at 18:35, his code doesn't crash when he does an insert but when I'm writing the exact same code, it crashes. Is that a Swift change (Maybe from Swift 6 ?)

@Jintae yeah, possibly something changed in iOS 18.

It's strange because when I look back at it, what you said is basic reference type knowledge and I didn't see it at first, but how did it work before ? Yeah maybe with some changes in iOS 18 but if someone has an answer, I'm super interested, thanks everyone !

@Jintae I was able to reproduce this on iOS 17.4. Apparently, ModelContext used to have a strong reference to its container (this creates a retain cycle!), but in iOS 18 it has become a weak reference (as it should).

Really ? Pardon me, maybe a noob question, but I went to check in the ModelContext and I found this : "public var container: ModelContainer { get }". But it's not a weak reference or maybe I'm in the wrong place.

@Jintae You are most likely just looking at the generated interface file which won't show private members. The line you found is just a computed property. You can check, at runtime, what references an object holds by using the Memory Graph Debugger. See my answer here for how to use it.

That's really cool, thanks for that :) I saw the weak reference from the context to his container. But is that wrong if I say that the context has twice his container (from computed property + the private weak one) ? I obviously miss something, sorry :x

@Jintae A computed property is effectively just a function. It doesn't store anything, so it doesn't count when one is analysing how many references some object holds.
